# How can I put lambda function in a nested stack in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using `serverless` to manage my AWS resources and come cross this plugin to support nested stacks: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-nested-stacks.

I have tried that but it seems that I can only put `Resources` in a nested stacks. I can't put serverless lambda functions in the nested stack because lambda function uses a different syntax than cloudformation.

For example, below is my lambda function defined in `serverless.yml`:

```
logoffHandler:
  handler: src/lambdas.lorcedLogoff
  name: lorcedLogoff
```

I can't put this definition in a nested stack, I will have to convert it to cloudformation syntax `AWS::Lambda::Function`. Do I understand it correctly? If I have to use cloudformation syntax to define everything, there is no point to use `serverless` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the serverless guide which define what is possible.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

You could define resources using cloudformation in Resources section.
I would say some pieces are only possible by adding them only with cloudformation.

I see your plugin use templates, so I believe you have to follow and create the cloudformation. Plugin is just an integration piece between serverless framework and cloudfromation.

Comment: Does this mean I can't use serverless syntax to define lambdas inside a nested stack?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Correct, I just looked deeper in the plugin code. It uses `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html
You have to prepare a template, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html ,I don't see a way how to use any kind of serverless syntax over here in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Try using slit stacks plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-split-stacks
Worked great for us